# Microsoft Access VBA code for Building a Pallet Packing List

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a Commercial Invoicing System developed in Access that our International Orders section uses.  The database itself runs near very well, as it is very simple and minimal.  However, now they want the packing list to auto build the pallets for them also.  Here is a quick breakdown of what I am trying to do:

### Product  |   CaseSize       |  CasesPerPallet

### 11111     |   11x12x9 @ 8lbs |  72

### 12221    |   11x12x9 @ 8lbs |  72

### 55555    |   11x14x10 @ 9lbs|  72

### ETC.

I have 7 different CaseSizes and 5 different CasesPerPallet quantities for all of our products.

What I would like is for my packing list to do this:

Example Joe's Grocery orders 150 cases of product 11111 and 138 cases of 12221 .. I want my report to "know" that I need 4 pallets of 72 keeping the products together by 1st productID and then leftovers (remainders) by CaseSize... i.e. 4 of the 11111 product would go with 66 of 12221.

However with many different sized cases I'm not sure how efficient this could be as sometimes we put the larger cases on the bottom and the smaller cases on the top of those to reduce pallet footprint.

I am thinking I need an if statement:

```
if [ProdID!CaseSize] = [ProdID!CaseSize] and QTY >72 Then
   subtract 72 from qty get remainder number; pallet++
    if [ProdID!CaseSize] = [ProdID!CaseSize] and QTY >72 Then
    subtract 72 from qty get remainder number; pallet++
   Else 
   End if
End if
```

So I'm thinking it needs to be a loop until it is no longer true then exit and show me total number of pallets.

The only other way I could think of doing this is to just add another field and have the order rep identify the pallet as she inputs the order.  This would cause her to put the order in according to pallet.

So she could enter 11111 x 72    pallet 1
                   11111 x 72    pallet 2
                   11111 x 6     pallet 3
                   12221 x 66    pallet 3
                   12221 x 72    pallet 4
  Then I could group my packing list by pallet but I don't want her to go through all this.

thank you in advance for your help!!

The attached picture shows an order I made up.  You can see they are all the same products but I do not have them grouped

[This picture shows how the packing list looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLWwn.png)

Comment: I totally don't have a clue what your problem exactly is. Could you try clarifying your question? What exactly doesn't work, and what exactly does? `'somehow subtract 72 from qty get remainder number` is just `qty - 72`, isn't it? Why are you comparing variables with themselves?

Comment: yes for that it is.  My end goal is she puts in an order and when she clicks the PackingListbtn it will generate a packing list based on best pallet configuration.   I am unsure of how to code this exactly.  The picture shows that I have two products with the same CaseSize.  So in theory I want that packing list to be broken down into 4 pallets with one of those pallets having 66 of product 20894 and 6 (remainder from 'qty-72) of 20852 ...